# difference between ZMQ software and language binding

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

What is the difference between ZMQ software (available at http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software) and language binding?

As i have installed language binding and my examples are working fine (written in python), then what is the use of ZMQ software?

Answer (score 2):

From their website:

> Language bindings
>
> ØMQ comes with the low-level C API. High-level bindings exist in 40+
>   languages including Python, Java, PHP, Ruby, C, C++, C#, Erlang, Perl,
>   and more.

In the case of the Python language bindings, if you install them via `pip` (and probably via `easy_install`) the install script will check if it finds the ØMQ libraries, and if it doesn't it will build a "bundled" version. That's probably why you didn't need to install them separately.

Answer (score 0):

The "ZMQ software" is what powers libzmq, which the language bindings rely on.  For example, if you want to use the bindings for python, you install pyzmq - but that has a requirement to have libzmq installed (assuming *nix OS here).  ZMQ itself is C++, and the language bindings are largely just wrappers around that.